# ArangoDB didn't start correctly during init

Tags: docker, arangodb

I try to use ArangoDB on Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64) using its Docker official image. To start a container, I run following command as suggest in the official docker image site

```
docker run -e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb
```

I check container status with `docker ps -a` and see that the `arangodb-instance` container did started and up for few minutes and then the container stopped running.
I check a container log with `docker logs arangodb-instance` and got ...

```
Initializing database...Hang on...
ArangoDB didn't start correctly during init
cat: can't open '/tmp/init-log': No such file or directory
```

I try on another version of docker images, the latest, 3.11.1 and 3.10, and I have the same error message.

I know there is a linux package manager for arangodb available and can be install with `apt-get`, but I need to have it on Docker container along side with my app in another container.

Could you help suggest if there is anything I miss or should have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

I just realize that my Ubuntu server with x86_64 **CPU DOES NOT have AVX** feature. The AVX is required for arangodb since version 3.9

With arangodb version 3.8.9, I can start arangodb in Docker container and access to arangosh just fine.